# I'm getting this error when I try to delete a row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm getting this error when I try to delete a row. Please who can help me!!!!

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 3.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

```
//
//  InboxTableViewController.m
//  Ribbit
//
//  Created by OnMac on 24/11/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 OnMac. All rights reserved.
//

#import "InboxTableViewController.h"
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@interface InboxTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation InboxTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.recipient = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.selectedMessage objectForKey:@"recipientIds"]];

    NSLog(@"Delete: %@", self.selectedMessage);

    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    if (currentUser) {

        NSLog(@"Currrent user: %@", currentUser.username);
    }

    else {

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
    }

}


-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {



    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
    [query whereKey:@"recipiendID" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

        }

        else{

//        We found messages!!!

            self.messages = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
//            NSLog(@"messages: %@", self.messages);
        }
    }];

    }

    else {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];


    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.messages count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    PFObject *message = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [message objectForKey:@"Username"];
//    NSLog(@"ALT: %@", message);
    NSString *fileType = [message objectForKey:@"fileType"];

    if ([fileType isEqualToString:@"image"]) {

    PFFile *im = [message objectForKey:@"file"];
    NSData *resumeData = [im getData];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:resumeData];
    }

    else{

        cell.imageView.image = nil;

    }


    return cell;
}





-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    self.selectedMessage = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    NSString *fileType = [self.selectedMessage objectForKey:@"fileType"];

    if ([fileType isEqualToString:@"image"]) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showImage" sender:self];




    }

    else{

//        File type is video


        PFFile *videoFile = [self.selectedMessage objectForKey:@"file"];
        NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:videoFile.url];
        self.moviePlayer.contentURL = fileUrl;
        [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];


//        Add it to the view controller so we can see it

        [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
        [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];




    }


}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

       PFObject *message1 = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [message1 deleteInBackground];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {




    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];


    }



   [self.tableView reloadData];



}

- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {


    [PFUser logOut];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];

}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showLogin"]) {

        [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];

    }

    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showImage"]) {

    [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
        ImageViewController *imageViewController = (ImageViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        imageViewController.message = self.selectedMessage;

    }
}

@end
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please just post relevant code. Most of the posted code is unrelated to the issue. And get rid of all the extra blank lines. Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: don't forget to reloadData

Comment: @Bejibun No, do not reloadData. Only one row is being removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please edit your code more. You have more white space than actual code, and pasting that much white space just makes the process longer.

Second, try reading the error message. It's saying that you are deleting a row from the `datasource` when you aren't removing it from the table. What I suspect is happening is inside your `commitEditingStyle` method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  PFObject *message1 = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [message1 deleteInBackground];
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
  }
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Look at what you're doing. There's a lot of issues here. First, you're deleting a message 100% of the time this method is called. That means you're always modifying your datasource. But look at your if statement - this means that you are not always deleting a row. Now you sometimes delete a message without deleting the row from the table. This WILL cause the crash.

Second - from what it sounds like, it sounds like you're deleting the message in the background. This is potentially a very bad thing. Why? Because if you're waiting on a delegate callback in an asynchronous fashion, then this will lead to very bad race conditions.

Your code should look like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    PFObject *message1 = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.messages removeObject:message1];
    [message1 deleteInBackground];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
  }
}
```

Note that I added `[self.messages removeObject:message1]` to make your `dataSource` consistent with the table immediately. I don't know what you were doing in `[PFObject deleteInBackground]`, but if you weren't immediately removing the message object from your `dataSource`, then you can run into bad issues.

Comment: Don't call `reloadData` after deleting (or inserting or reloading) a row from the table.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to take that out in the copy paste. Editing

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! but still the same problem, I'm sure that problem is in `commitEditingStyle`. When I added this line `[self.messages removeObject:message1]` it gives me an error: No visible @interface for "NSArray" declares the selector 'removeObject:'. Is Build Failed. Thanks again for your help and time!!!!

Comment: You're using an `NSArray` instead of an `NSMutableArray` as your `dataSource`. This is bad if you need to edit your table. Mutable means you're able to change it, while the `NSArray` means it's read only. Think about this logically for a second. If you're running a store, would you want a read-only inventory list? Would this make sense - your inventory list you can't change based on what sold? That's what you have right now, a list you cannot edit. You need to change self.messages to be a `NSMutableArray`. You can do this by `self.messages = [objects mutableCopy];`

Comment: Dear LyricalPanda is not working, I don't know what to do When I write just this code 
`if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
         
            self.selectedMessage = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
          
                [self.selectedMessage deleteInBackground];
           
            [self.tableView reloadData]; 
            }` Is working, but I need to do a refresh to disappear the object, I want to disappear immediate. Help me please how to do!!!!

Comment: You need to remove `self.selectedMessage` from `self.messages`. My previous post shows you how to modify self.messages to be `NSMutableArray`, which will allow you to use `[self.messages removeObject:self.selectedMessage]`. Literally all you have to do is do `self.messages = [objects mutableCopy]`, change the declaration of `self.messages` to an `NSMutableArray` and use the code I provided.

Comment: I did but the same problem there is my code `PFObject *message1 = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    self.mut = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:self.messages];
                    [self.mut removeObject:message1];
          
                    [message1 deleteInBackground];
                    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`

I serched on google and there are many with this problem but without answer. :(

Comment: The problem is you're not modifying `self.messages`. Your table is populating the data based off `self.messages`, but in the code you just put, you're modifying `self.mut`. They are two completely different lists. Do exactly what I told you in my previous post. Don't create `self.mut`, simply change `self.messages` to a `NSMutableArray` and do `self.messages = [objects mutableCopy]`. Right now you're doing `self.messages = objects` after you do query. Just change it to `self.messages = [objects mutableCopy]`. That's it. I'm literally giving you the answer and you keep doing other things.